# Setting global properties for RTC Jazz Build definition

Tags: build, rtc, jazz

I have several Build Definitions in RTC/Jazz and i use a variable to set out DB-Release in various Build Definitions

- Build-Lib
- Build-Server-App
- Build-Run-Test-Server
- Build-Client-App
- Build-Run-Test-Client

and in all Definitions i use the Property DB_SCHEMA,

```
DB_SCHEMA = 8.1
```

once we update our DB and use a new Schema i have to set the Build Property up to

```
DB_SCHEMA = 8.2
```

now i must update all Build-Definitions... and if i forget one or i misspell something, then my boss gets mad at me - joking, but honestly, i don't want to make mistakes

--> how can i define a global Property that can be used in all Build-Definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see [any global property in the help page](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rtc/v1r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.build.doc%2Ftopics%2Fr_buildprop.html), so you might consider developing a program:

- using the [RTC Java API](https://jazz.net/library/article/1229)
- for each build definition, setting the property to the expected value (as [in this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/111596/how-to-update-build-definition-property-values-with-rtc-java-api))

  ```
  IBuildDefinition definition = (IBuildDefinition) buildDefinition.getWorkingCopy();
  definition.setProperty("propertyName","");
  definition = buildClient.save(definition, monitor);
  ```

Comment: Hello VonC again - you are a real smart guy - this solution will work for me!!! i'm still impress of what you can and what you can achive! this is a good answer! (but takes some effort ^^)

Comment: ok, i did now implement your answer - it took quite a while but now i'm done (it took time because i was working on something different, not because it was difficult to do)... it works fine for us now! thanks a lot again!

Comment: @MartinFrank Great! Could you add an answer with the main part of your implementation?

Comment: sorry to ask again, but can you add the property for the 'enabled'-button in the scheduled-tabulator? your solution works so good i want to widen this approach - now i can enable/disable all nightly build-jobs...  so i can stop it when i know the server will be down...

Comment: i whish i could even ++ your answer this here was a really goody and made my work far more easy!!

Comment: sorry to say that... i found it!

Comment: i don't know why i didn't see this earlier, but it's obvious *shame* workingCopy.getBuildSchedule().setScheduleEnabled(isEnabled)...

Comment: @MartinFrank Indeed. I didn't have access to the doc, so I wouldn't have found it as quickly as you did.

Answer (score 1):

Ok VonC here is my solution:

one Part is an RTC-Adapter which handles Connections from and to the RTC base:

(it provides further getter/setters wich are not relevant for this solution - i purged them)

### RTC-Adapter

```
public class RtcAdapter {

//yes i know - having hardcoded user/pass is bad, ignore this - image it's in a property file or set by a popup dialog
private static final String repositoryURI = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/ccm";
private static final String userId = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
private static final String password = "xxxxxxxxxx";
private static final String projectAreaName = "xxxxxxxxxx";

private ITeamRepository teamRepository = null;
private IProgressMonitor monitor = new NullProgressMonitor();
private IProjectArea projectArea = null;
private ITeamBuildClient buildClient = null;

//i'm implementing a singleton class - you can argue with mie if it's a good approach
private static final RtcAdapter inst = new RtcAdapter();

private RtcAdapter(){       
    super();
}

public ITeamRepository getTeamRepository() {
    return teamRepository;
}

public IProgressMonitor getMonitor() {
    return monitor;
}

public IProjectArea getProjctArea(){
    return projectArea;
}

public ITeamBuildClient getBuildClient(){
    return buildClient;
}

private void setTeamRepository(ITeamRepository teamRepositoryIn) {
    teamRepository = teamRepositoryIn;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param repositoryURI
 * @param userId
 * @param password
 * @param monitor
 * @return
 * @throws TeamRepositoryException 
 */

private ITeamRepository login(String repositoryURI, String userId,String password, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws TeamRepositoryException {       

    ITeamRepository teamRepository = TeamPlatform.getTeamRepositoryService().getTeamRepository(repositoryURI);
    teamRepository.registerLoginHandler(new LoginHandler(userId, password));
    teamRepository.login(monitor);
    return teamRepository;
}

/**
 * LoginHandler required by login function
 *
 */
private static class LoginHandler implements ILoginHandler, ILoginInfo {

    private String fUserId;
    private String fPassword;

    private LoginHandler(String userId, String password) {
        fUserId = userId;
        fPassword = password;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return fUserId;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return fPassword;
    }

    public ILoginInfo challenge(ITeamRepository repository) {
        return this;
    }

}

public static RtcAdapter inst() {
    return inst;
}

public boolean connect() {

    TeamPlatform.startup();

    System.out.println("Team Platform Startup");
    try {
        IProgressMonitor monitor = new NullProgressMonitor();
        setTeamRepository(login(repositoryURI, userId, password, monitor));
        System.out.println("Logged in");            

        IProcessClientService processClient= (IProcessClientService) getTeamRepository().getClientLibrary(IProcessClientService.class);
        URI uri= URI.create(projectAreaName.replaceAll(" ", "%20"));
        projectArea = (IProjectArea) processClient.findProcessArea(uri, null, RtcAdapter.inst().getMonitor() );

        buildClient = (ITeamBuildClient) getTeamRepository().getClientLibrary(ITeamBuildClient.class);

        System.out.println("projet area = "+projectArea.getName() );
    } catch (TeamRepositoryException e) {
        System.out.println("TeamRepositoryException : " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public void disconnect(){
    System.out.println("Logged out");
    TeamPlatform.shutdown();
}

}
```

the other part is the working Class, i called it BuildDefinitionHelper (what a great name, haha)

### BuildDefinitionHelper

```
public class BuildDefinitionHelper {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new BuildDefinitionHelper().startUp();  //not-so-nice startup, but i don't mind
}

private final String[] adaPublishDefinitionList = new String[]{
        "publish ada develop-40",
        "publish ada develop-40 nightly",
        "publish ada develop-54",
        "publish ada develop-54 nightly",
        "publish ada develop-56",
        "publish ada develop-56 nightly",
        "publish ada develop-58",
        "publish ada develop-58 nightly",
};  

private final String BUILD_NR = "BUILD_NR";
private final String MAJOR = "MAJOR";
private final String MINOR = "MINOR";

private void startUp() {

    final int major = 57;
    final int minor = 11;
    final int build = 1;

    //connect
    if (RtcAdapter.inst().connect() ){

        //getting  required resources - a singleton is helpful here (look above)
        IProgressMonitor pMon = RtcAdapter.inst().getMonitor();         
        ITeamBuildClient buildClient = RtcAdapter.inst().getBuildClient();

        try {               

            for (String adaPublish: adaPublishDefinitionList ){                 
                //get build definition
                IBuildDefinition workingCopy = getBuildDefinition(adaPublish, buildClient, pMon);   

                //seting properties
                String propMajor = getFormattededInteger(major);
                String propMinor = getFormattededInteger(minor);
                String propBuild = getFormattededInteger(build);

                setBuildProperty(MAJOR, propMajor, workingCopy);
                setBuildProperty(MINOR, propMinor, workingCopy);
                setBuildProperty(BUILD_NR, propBuild, workingCopy);

                //store changes
                saveBuildDefinition(workingCopy, buildClient, pMon);
            }

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TeamRepositoryException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //at the end: disconnect
        RtcAdapter.inst().disconnect();         
    }

}

private void saveBuildDefinition(IBuildDefinition definition, ITeamBuildClient buildClient, IProgressMonitor progressMonitor) throws TeamBuildDuplicateItemException, IllegalArgumentException, TeamRepositoryException {
    buildClient.save(definition, progressMonitor);
}

private String getFormattededInteger(int value) {
    if (value >= 0 && value <= 9){
        return "00"+value;
    }
    if (value >= 10 && value <= 99){
        return "0"+value;
    }
    return ""+value;
}

private IBuildDefinition getBuildDefinition(String buildDefinitionName, ITeamBuildClient buildClient, IProgressMonitor progressMonitor) throws IllegalArgumentException, TeamRepositoryException {
    IBuildDefinition buildDefinition = buildClient.getBuildDefinition(buildDefinitionName, progressMonitor );
    IBuildDefinition definition = (IBuildDefinition) buildDefinition.getWorkingCopy();
    return definition;
}

private void setBuildProperty(String propertyName, String propertyValue, IBuildDefinition definition ) throws TeamBuildDuplicateItemException, IllegalArgumentException, TeamRepositoryException {
    definition.setProperty(propertyName,propertyValue);
    System.out.println("set "+propertyName+" to "+ propertyValue+" in Build Definition "+definition.getId() );
}

private void printBuildDefinition(String[] buildDefinitionList, ITeamBuildClient buildClient, IProgressMonitor progressMonitor) throws IllegalArgumentException, TeamRepositoryException {
    for (String buildDefinitionName: buildDefinitionList ){
        IBuildDefinition buildDefinition = buildClient.getBuildDefinition(buildDefinitionName, progressMonitor );
        IBuildDefinition definition = (IBuildDefinition) buildDefinition.getWorkingCopy();
        System.out.println("name = "+buildDefinitionName+" definition = "+definition);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: well i have to say that to you - you have been a great help in many cases - i am really glad that you are here on StackOverFlow!!!

Comment: No problem: I am here every single day (http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122976/6309)